# Persuade Access 2007 to use a .UDL file/oledb connection?

Tags: ms-access, odbc, oledb, ms-access-2007, interbase

Is there any way of coaxing Access 2007 into using a .UDL file?

Specifically, one of our older products uses an Interbase 6.0 database. My client would like to link to his database, for read/write, using Access 2007 (in the short term).

While this isn't my preferred way of doing things at all, given it's all single-user and the other access to the Interbase database is all done via a Delphi 7 client, I can't really just say 'no' - at least, not until I have the time to 'properly' give him what he wants.

I don't have any other kind of driver that Access could use, although I have made a .UDL file that successfully links (via IBoledb) to the database. Stupidly, I just assumed that a modern version of Access would be able to use a .UDL file...

So, I tried to get Access 2007 to make sense of that .UDL file (even tried renaming it to .DSN and messing around with some of the values in the file) but to no avail. It seems that the only way you can get Access to link to Interbase would be via a (purchased, third-party) Interbase ODBC driver.

Anyone know different? Can I somehow get Access to 'link tables' with Interbase via a .UDL link?

Cheers!

Comment: Access has not shipped with built-in direct access to Borland database products and their successors for nearly 10 years. Since 1999 or so you've always needed third-party drivers for Borland/Firebird/dBase, etc. (well, in regard to xBase, if you want read/write and not just read-only).

Comment: I'll close this - it seems that you can't get Access to use a regular UDL file. Which is weird, given what you can get it to do via OLEDB to SQL Server. I don't see that the Interbase side of it should matter, but I guess it does. :-)

Comment: *Don't close it.*  Some of us are still saddled with trying to "get there from here", and having this Q&A available will at least serve as a warning sign to others that are searching for the same answer and come across this in their results.  Believe me, if I do find an answer, I'll be back here in a heartbeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible. Although Access will happily talk to SQL Server using OLEDB, there doesn't seem to be a way to get it to use OLEDB connections to other databases.

At least now that I can 'accept my own answers' I can 'close' this question. :-)

Comment: Before finding your q/a, I spent 20 minutes trying to make it work, and am left wondering what the intended purpose for a .udl file ever was.