# Accessing (read only) a Firebird database with MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007

I would like to know how to read information stored in a Firebird Database and use it in an MS Access 2007 application that I'm about to write. The Firebird database will not be updated via MS Access 2007.

Comment: ODBC is the most obvious interface.

Comment: See: http://www.connectionstrings.com/firebird

Comment: @Remou: don't you think it's helpful to direct the original poster to the Access-native way of doing things? That is, linked tables via ODBC, vs. OLEDB (which all has to be done in code)?

Answer (score 0):

**This is a real problem**, and [you're not the only one asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283355/persuade-access-2007-to-use-a-udl-file-oledb-connection).  Access has native support for ODBC, which is ok for getting things in and out, except when the ODBC driver is dodgy.  Near as I can tell, there really isn't a concept of OLEDB interfaces in Access, and it appears doubtful that you "can get there from here".  Believe me, if I do find an answer, I'll be back here in a heartbeat to update this post.

Answer (score -1):

Thought it is very late to response...I have started learning firebird with ms access since last 6 month, as I am not a programmer nor I have any degree in computer. Finally I have successed to configure all things in firebird and link table with ms access.
Basically I created all the table with flamerobbin GUI tool, created generator and trigger. last link with obdc driver with ms access as linktable.

In ms access I created relationship of required tables and created forms as link vs child. Now everything is working fine.

Most error come due to null constraint. However if one has created all triggers and generator he will face no issue.

I am very impress by the Firebird database as it the best of the best tool and easiest as well.

Comment: Can you please provide more details? As it stands, your answer is too general, and thus unlikely to be helpful on its own. On the other hand, describing the steps you did in more details plus providing a few samples would make it immediately more useful.